# How to pass Parameter to a partial view: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I have a partial view that renders one control on the page, this control is for certain fields that are `long`. This is how I defined it:

```
@model long
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(x => Model)
```

I'm trying to render this partial view in other views with something like:

```
@Html.Partial("MultiSelect/partialView", @Model.longField)
```

This give me an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exception.

Please guide me about the right syntax to achieve this.

Comment: Check if @Model is null.

Comment: It is Null, I want the user to fill the form.

Comment: How can you access property of null object, set model to new Model()

Comment: Thanks Nitin, it was a silly mistake. Please post you answer if you'd like, so I can select it.

Comment: Posted, please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `@Model` is `null`. If yes, try to create object of your model to pass to view. You cannot access property of null object as you have done.

```
 var model= new YourViewModel();
 return View(model);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two things being mistaken here, though it depends on your solution.

1. Check your path to the partial view's name. You can only write `MultiSelect/partialView` if the `MultiSelect` folder and the `partialView.cshtml` are in the same folder as the view from which you are calling `Html.Partial(...)`. That is, your folder structure is something like this:

   ```
   Views
    | YourViewFolder
        YourView.cshtml
        | MultiSelect folder
           partialView.cshtml
   ```

In other words, in your code, you specify a relative path to your current view. (Note that your partial view can also be in `/Views/Shared`, Razor will find it in that case as well.) If your fodler structure is not like that above (or is not in `/Views/Shared/`, then you must specify the path relative to your project like this: `/Views/.../MultiSelect/partialView` where `...` is any directory in between `Views` and `MultiSelect`.

Other thing that you should check is that `@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(x => Model)` line is missing a right paren `)` from the end of it, I am not sure if this is a copy-paste error or it is like that in your view.

Comment: It's in the shared folder, and that right `)` is a copy-paste problem. It was rather a silly mistake, I didn't pass a new model to the view! :D